# Escape sequences in STAssertEqualStrings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unit-testing

I'm writing a discovery test against the Cocoa API as I ramp up on all things Mac related. I'm currently trying to discover the best method for URL encoding a string. Using the Google toolbox for Mac I have a unit test that I *intentionally* cause a failure in:

```
 NSString* expected = @"ab%%20c";
 NSString* encoded = @"ab c";
 STAssertEqualStrings(expected, encoded, @"Expected [%s] actual [%s]", [expected UTF8String], [encoded UTF8String]);
```

and it complains "ab        P != ab c" The garbage it dumps in the output is throwing me. It's as if the percent sign isn't properly escaped but I know it is. My main question is how do I get a properly formed error message so I can be sure I'm dealing with apples instead of oranges?

***update**
Stackoverflow was removing the garbage in my original post. The above failure is intentional to illustrate a problem with the failure message. I'm concerned with the garbage that shows in the failure message as it does cleanly not detail what's in the actual string. The failure says something like "assertion failed ab[apple-symbol]c != ab c" where I get an apple character in the message instead of a percent sign. In practice encoded would be the return of a method call and I'd like to inspect, using the assertion failure message, the contents of the string.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The expected does not equal to the encoded, so the assert fails. Seems like it's working correctly. Or am I missing something?

Comment: See above update for clarity.

Comment: I forget why I was having trouble here. If you see, I'm converting NSStrings to C strings inline before interpolating the values which was adding unnecessary complexity. It's a non issue now since Xcode has changed several times over.

Answer (score 2):

You’re confusing backslash escaping, which is applied at compile time, with percent-sign escaping, which is applied to format string by `printf`-like functions and methods. Since `expected` isn’t being processed by such a function, the percent signs are not escaping anything.

That said, unless StackOverflow is mangling your message, the percent signs should be present in “ab%%c != ab c”.